# How to run a single protractor testsuite in jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to run my protractor tests in Jenkins and its working. The problem is, running the tests on a docker container and use multiple headless browsers doesnt work, because my test is using actions like hovering an element. My idea was to use multiple test suites:

- local: not headless, for presentations
- external: headless (test cases without actions like hovering an element), Jenkins

I added the suites in the protractor.conf.js file.
Typing
`protractor protractor.conf.js --suite local` using the terminal works fine and as expected, but in my **Jenkinsfile.feature** it says
`npm run e2e...`, which runs also the testsuite I dont want to be executed.
So my Jenkins tests fail, just because the wrong testsuite is executed.
Replacing `npm run e2e...` with
`protractor protractor.conf.js --suite local` in the **Jenkinsfile.feature** doesnt work neither. I hope there is a way to tell Jenkins what suite to run. Thank you

Comment: Can you explain what `npm run e2e...` is? What's the ellipses for? I would expect your command to look like this: `npm run e2e --suite local`. Is that what you are doing? Also, to run inside docker container you would need to use `docker exec` command.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question sounds like 'how can one develop a website' I'll try to walk you through the steps. But your question it too broad especially given that you didn't provide your error stack and the content of package.json, config file, docker file and jenkins job you're running

You gotta break your task into multiple layers (and this relates to any parameter you want, headless or multiple suites) and resolve them one by one

1. Make sure your protractor can take this parameter, by passing from the CLI. For example

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --suite local
```

But don't forget to add default value if nothing is passed

2. Once 1 is tested and works, go to the next layer, which should be docker in your case. Open Dockerfile where you declare the image, and add environment variables that you will be passing to protractor. Define the command to run your script once a container is spun up from your image
3. When you have your docker image working as expected, find out how to pass variables to that image when spinning up a container. Normally it should be like following

```
docker run -e SUITE=“regression” protractor_image
```

4. When you have the image in Jenkins master or slave, and you can run tests from CLI, you can work on your job. Again, depends on what you're doing pipeline job or regular freelance job, your steps maybe different. But the logic remains the same. You need to add a job, and make it run tests by hardcoding parameters
5. When the job works, add input parameters and ensure that can be used

I'm sure you'll have questions about each item or the list, so I'd suggest to open a new question for each and provide more details for them. Good luck